# Multiple instances of node.js on one machine and npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Today I'm installed Node.js first time on my Fedora 24 via downloading tar with latest version, then it was unpacked in some directory on my computer.

Next, I'm tried to install globally package http-server for playing with it. But access denied error occurs. It happens because on my Fedora already installed nodejs as dependency of some other packages, well, do not care about it.

And npm-cli.js executed via node, which it finds via `env node` command, and it finds system node, but I need to execute npm by my node, which installed in some other directory.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions include:

- Using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
- Manually changing the order of your `$PATH` so that the path for the version of node you want to use for your session comes before the path for the system copy.

Comment: Thanks, I try nvm later. Now I simple execute npm in this way: `/path/to/my/node/bin/node /path/to/my/node/bin/npm install http-server -g`.

Comment: *or* as mentioned `PATH=/path/to/my/node/bin:$PATH npm install http-server -g` for temporary use, *or* `export PATH=/path/to/my/node/bin:$PATH` (then `npm install http-server -g`) for longer term use (you may put it in your bash profile or similar for an even more permanent effect).